# 3D Scan to VFX - Matching Camera

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera

I want to scan my bedroom so I can add 3D elements on it.

I want to make a still photo. How can I match the 3D object to the camera, and which is the best practice to that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For still images I would like to recommend [fSpy](https://fspy.io/). It is a free open source tool, that allows to set up a camera based on perspective lines from your photo. It is free and easy, no special equipment is requared.

[image]

fSpy files can be loaded using a built-in add-on that you should activate in user preferences:

[image]